# Calling a procedure within another class

Tags: vb.net, outlook, add-in

I've created an add-in for outlook 2010.  I have a ribbon that has a button on it.  When you click that button, I want it to call a procedure in the ThisAddIn.vb.

There are two files: ThisAddin.vb and Ribbon.vb.

I've tried several things to no avail. I've also set all the procedures to public.

Call Testing123()

Call ThisAddIn.Testing123()

Etc

How do I properly call this procedure?

```
****Ribbon1.vb****
Imports Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon


Public Class MyOutlookTab

    Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Call Testing123()

    End Sub

End Class


***ThisAddIn.vb***
Public Class ThisAddIn

    Public Sub Testing123()
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("It Works!")

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for everyones comments but I found the solution in an example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee620548.aspx where they talk about adding a ribbon to the meeting request (2/3's of the way down).

It's actually quite simple.  You call the procedure using the "Global"

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Testing123()
```

Nothing else is needed.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are trying to reference class methods without creating a class.

You have three options to make this work:

1) Convert `ThisAddIn` to a `Module`. Then there won't be any issues accessing the `Testing123` method as you currently have it.

2) Convert `ThisAddin.Testing123` to a `Shared` method, i.e.:

```
Public Shared Sub Testing123()
```

Then you would access as follows:

```
Call ThisAddin.Testing123()
```

3) Create an instance of the ThisAddIn class prior to using its methods:

```
Dim oAddIn As New ThisAddIn
Call oAddIn.Testing123()
```

**Update**

It appears that addins are treated differently that standard classes.

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608621.aspx) contains specific implementation guidance for accessing AddIn functionality from other types of solutions.

Based on this article, you need to take a couple of additional steps:

1) Create an interface to expose the functionality from your AddIn:

```
<ComVisible(True)> _
Public Interface IAddInUtilities
    Sub Testing123()
End Interface
```

2) Add a utilities class to your addin project:

```
<ComVisible(True)> _
<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)> _
Public Class AddInUtilities
    Implements IAddInUtilities

    Public Sub Testing123() Implements IAddInUtilities.Testing123
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("It Works!")
    End Sub
End Class
```

3) Add the following to ThisAddIn to expose the utilities to external callers:

```
Private utilities As AddInUtilities

Protected Overrides Function RequestComAddInAutomationService() As Object
    If utilities Is Nothing Then
        utilities = New AddInUtilities()
    End If
    Return utilities
End Function
```

4) I am a little unclear on the exact syntax needed for the last step since I don't have automation installed in office, but you will need to do something along these lines:

```
' OutlookTest should be changed to the name of the project ThisAddIn is in
Dim addIn As Office.COMAddIn = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.COMAddIns.Item("OutlookTest")
Dim utilities As OutlookTest.IAddInUtilities = TryCast( _
    addIn.Object, OutlookTest.IAddInUtilities)
utilities.Testing123()
```

Comment: ok, I tried option 2 and I was able to recognize testing123 within the MyOutlookTab class but... When I converted the sub to shared it caused other issues with the code (would not recognize me.application.createItem... which is used but I did not include for simplicity sake)

Comment: Then I tried option 3 and this seems like its gonna work because it was able to find the procedure but I get an error. "Argument not specified for parameter 'Factory' of 'Public sub New(factory as Microsoft.blahblahblha)'.  Never seen this one before.  Thanks for your help, I think I'm getting closer

Comment: @user7801: Based on that additional info, option 3 may be your best bet.

Comment: ok, for option 3 it wanted me to create a "Sub New" procedure because I'm obviously trying to call it.  What do I have to put in it?

Comment: @user7801: You shouldn't need to put anything in it, but you could, for safety sake, put `MyBase.New()`.

Comment: I tried MyBase.New() as well as MyClass.New() and it gives me the same error about the Factory of Public sub new.   If I don't put anything in the Sub New, the error is: First statement of this 'Sub New' must be a call to 'MyBase.New' or 'MyClass.New' because base class 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.OutlookAddInBase' of 'Update_Emailer.ThisAddIn' does not have an accessible 'Sub New' that can be called with no arguments.  Again, thanks for your help, I've bee racking my brain all day on this one.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/707s02fy.aspx  says to try MyBase.New(Nothing).... that didn't work either.  hmm need to dig a little deeper

Comment: Can you show the full error message that you get so I can see the full factory name it is expecting? That might help.

Comment: This is the error I get in the Sub New() procedure:  First statement of this 'Sub New' must be a call to 'MyBase.New' or 'MyClass.New' because base class 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.OutlookAddInBase' of 'Update_Emailer.ThisAddIn' does not have an accessible 'Sub New' that can be called with no arguments.

Comment: @malt_man: Thank your for the exception; it shows that you are creating an actual addin as opposed to just having the class named that way. Unfortunately, this makes it more complex to implement. I have updated the answer with a link to the appropriate MSDN documentation and the steps I think you need to take to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into it further. However I did find a simple solution, see comment. It's frustrating that the addin si so different. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new instance of the class before you can call it in vb.net!

So something like should allow you to call it..

```
Public Class MyOutlookTab

    Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim testing As New ThisAddIn()
        Call testing.Testing123()

    End Sub

End Class
```