# How To Develop My Own Excel Add-in in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-addins, vba

I am trying to create an Excel Add-in using Vb.Net. I've started an Excel 2007 Add-in Project in VS2010. Sadly, I am not good with vb.net; I am more a VB6 developer in this regard, and my ThisAddin.vb code is:

```
Public Class ThisAddin

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup

    End Sub

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown

    End Sub

    ' test function; simple
    Public Function getRowCount() As Long
        Dim thisWB As Workbook = Me.Application.ThisWorkbook
        Dim activWS As Worksheet
        activWS = thisWB.ActiveSheet
        Return activWS.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    End Function
End Class
```

I've also added a Ribbon item (via Add New Item... menu option) in designer mode (not xml) - and then add a button. Then I go to code and try to call the function and I get this error when using:

```
MsgBox(Globals.ThisAddIn.getRowCount())
```

Which I got from this link: [Calling a procedure within another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480680/calling-a-procedure-within-another-class)

[image]

To be honest, I've been trying a myriad things and I've been getting so many errors. I've been looking online as well for a tutorial on creating my own Excel Addin from scratch with no real luck. I would like not to use Add-In-Express since that's a third party app and I have to create an Excel add-in for my company from scratch.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can create a vb.net coded Excel Addin (2007) that I can use as a template or guide? I've tried several and many rely on Add-In-express and I really cannot go that way. I have a lot of VBA code (natural VBA so it's in a module in an my excel files' VBA/Developer section) and I think I can translate those from VBA/VB6 to VB.Net format so that's not my concern. It is really about getting to code my own Excel Addin in VB.Net. Any help would really be great. Thank you.

*note: I would also like not to have to ask coworkers (or do myself) to just add to the quick access toolbar the functions and subs I've created since that's really not a solution, considering that those buttons will be there when they create or open another workbook. Essentially, I've got to create my own excel addin in vb.net. Thank you once again.

Comment: It may be a case of learning by working through the errors. For example, [Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC Error](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12893711/1115360) might help with that one. Also, be sure to use Option Strict On.

Comment: What tutorials or walk-throughs have you done already that show how to build an Excel add-in?

Comment: You can try something like `Dim thisWB = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook`

Answer (score 2):

The issue has to do with the definitions in `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel` and `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`.  To code an "Interop" version you could use this:

```
   Public Function getRowCount() As Long

        Dim thisWB As Excel.Workbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
        Dim activWS As Excel.Worksheet = CType(thisWB.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet)

        Return activWS.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    End Function
```

To extend the functionality of the Native objects and use VSTO, you could do it like this:

```
    Public Function getRowCount() As Long

        Dim NativeWorkbook As Excel.Workbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
        Dim NativeWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(NativeWorkbook.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet)

        Dim thisWB As Workbook = Nothing
        Dim activWS As Worksheet = Nothing

        If NativeWorkbook IsNot Nothing Then
            thisWB = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(NativeWorkbook)
        End If

        If NativeWorksheet IsNot Nothing Then
            activWS = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(NativeWorksheet)
        End If

        Return activWS.UsedRange.Rows.Count

End Function
```

This is a function you can put in `ThisAddin.vb` that will create a new Worksheet.  Note that this function names the Worksheet and adds it to the end.

```
Public Function AddWorkSheet(sheetName As String) As Worksheet

    Dim wk = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet = Nothing

    Try
        ws = CType(wk.Sheets.Add(, wk.Sheets(wk.Sheets.Count)), Worksheet)
        ws.Name = sheetName
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    Finally
        AddWorkSheet = ws
    End Try

End Function
```

To use this outside of `ThisAddin.vb` you could do something like this:

```
 Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
 Dim newSheetName As String
     .
     '
 ws = Globals.ThisAddIn.AddWorkSheet(newSheetName)
```

Comment: Thank you, Jim.. I will try this when I get hold of my computer again.. May I ask you as well if you have any place or link or book to buy that will show me more of how to code for Excel addins? I never knew there was a `NativeWorksheet` object and will definitely look into it... I'm sooo looking forward to trying this out!!!!

Comment: @RDC I would start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668205.aspx).  Not sure there are many books available.  I spent a lot of time just using the MSDN documentation,

Comment: I actually went through that link before posting here.. I didn't save any link so I didn't post any.. only because they didn't really help me. I basically tried to transcribe VBA to VB.Net in my post above. Having said that.... I tried the code and it works! However, I can't get it to work when I want to add a new sheet and assign it to an object variable that I can use.. Can you help me out a bit more?  Please?

Comment: @RDJ - I updated my answer to include a function that creates and returns a Worksheet. Here is another [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386107(v=vs.120).aspx) that you may want to bookmark.